# spark sql load parqet with special character in path

Tags: sql, pyspark, hive

I am using pyspark sql to load files into table following

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/user/hive/warehouse/students' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE test_load;
```

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-dml-load.html

It complains:

> pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: load data input path does not exist
> when the path string has timestamp in the directory structure like
> XX/XX/2021-03-02T20:04:27+00:00/file.parquet

It works with path without timestamp. How to work it around?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen any file system that support '2021-03-02T20:04:27+00:00' as folder name or file name. usually ":" and "+" signs are considered as reserved characters and  you can't use them in file/folder naming.

read file system manual you are using for "reserved words"

change your datetime format to something that is supported by the operating system file system like 'yyyy-mm-ddThhMMSS' ex: '2021-03-02T200427'